# Visual Studio 2012 Preparation - install warning?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am getting warnings at the end of my VS2012Pro install that I do not understand and was wondering if anyone else had the same issue or knew of a reason/fix. I receive 2 warnings that are almost identical:

Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation
The system cannot find the file specified.
and
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Preparation
The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm installing from an ISO. I've tried mounting with Virtual Clone Drive and just extracting the files with 7-Zip and using the exe. Both scenarios give the warnings.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered adding samples of the warnings to your question? It gives the specific information required to diagnose the problem and will make it easier for others to find this question.

Comment: I am also getting the same problem